# Orientation Problem in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, orientation

Hi All
I am implementing an application which uses TabBar and Navigation Controller. In this application I need to change the orientation of a specific view(Photo Gallery View in my app )(want to implementation orientation functionality). I have set boolean value YES in all the view controller's shouldautoroateorientation. by doing this all the view are rotate. I just want to rotate only one specific view. anybody have idea about it Pls Reply.

Thanks in advance....:)

Answer (score 1):

The only views that should return "YES" for shouldAutoRotateOrientation are those that actually want to rotate. Note that this means, sometimes the navigation and tab bar controllers will return YES and sometimes they should return NO.

I haven't actually tried this, but set it up and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

I started with a new Tab Bar application, then create a class "MyTabBarController" (derived from UITabBarController) and changed the MainWindow.xib to use MyTabBarController instead of a UITabBarController. Then I added the following code to MyTabBarController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    BOOL result = interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    if (self.selectedIndex == 0)
        result = YES;
    return result;
}
```

Once I did that, only the first view controller would rotate, the second one would not.

However, I notice that this method is only called when the device actually rotates, once in landscape, tapping on another tab will bring that up in landscape. So maybe what you want to do can't be done exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you evaluating the orientation in shouldAutorotateOrientation? if you are targeting the phone, your implementation should look like this in the view that you want to allow rotation on

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

and this in all other views

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: Hi Friends Thanks for your great suggestion... I got the solution here

Comment: Pls click on this link and go to the page no 42 of this pdf file... It Works For Me...http://docs.huihoo.com/apple/iphone/iphone-application-programming/06-ViewControllers.pdf

Comment: Pls ignore previous solution and click on this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS.pdf

Comment: what exactly was the solution? you simply linked to the view controller programming guide.